# Change currency position according to currency in wordpress

Tags: switch-statement, woocommerce, currency

Googled and searched but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I am building a woocommerce website which has 2 currencies: KRW and USD.

I have two buttons which switch between these currencies.

When KRW is selected, price display 10,000W and when USD is selected, it displays 100$.

What I want is to display $100 when USD is selected.

I tried in my functions.php:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_price_format','change_currency_pos');

function change_currency_pos( $currency_pos, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'USD': $currency_pos = '%1$s%2$s'; break;
          case 'KRW': $currency_pos = '%2$s%1$s'; break;
     }
     return $currency_pos;
}
```

also tried:

```
    function change_currency_pos() {
        $currency_pos = get_option('woocommerece_currency');

        switch($currency_pos) {
            case 'USD': $format = '%1$s%2$s'; break;
            case 'KRW': $format = '%2$s%1$s'; break;
        }
        return $currency_pos;
        }

   add_filter('woocommerce_price_format','change_currency_pos');
```

Both didn't work. :(

Can somebody help please. Thank you.

Comment: How does the site know whether KRW or USD is selected? You should be able to filter `get_option` and target the `woocommerce_currency_pos` option.

Comment: I have a currency switcher plugin which gives me an option to switch currency around.

Comment: In the code you just added you have the wrong variables passed from the `woocommerce_price_format` filter. `$format` and `$currency_pos` are available. See `wc-formatting-functions.php`. 

What I was trying to ask is how does the plugin know which currency to display? `$_GET` variables? I don't know what plugin you are using and so don't know how it works and thus can only guess how you should filter the option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess since I don't know what plugin you are using or how it works. I am going to assume that it adds a `$_GET` variable named `currency` to the end of your URL. `www.example.com&currency=KRW` But idea is that you set a value for the `woocommerce_currency_pos` option based on some data provided by the currency plugin.

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_currency_pos', 'change_currency_position' );
function change_currency_position(){
    if( ! isset( $_GET['currency'] ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( 'USD' == $_GET['currency'] ){
        return 'left';
    } elseif ( 'KRW' == $_GET['currency'] ){
        return 'right';
    } 
}
```

Alternatively, I could assume that "right" is the default currency position. And that you only need to filter the option in the instance where the site is displayed in USD-mode. In which case you would only need the following

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_currency_pos', 'change_currency_position' );
function change_currency_position(){
    if( isset( $_GET['currency'] && 'USD' == $_GET['currency'] ){
        return 'left';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Though it didn't work for me, I got the idea. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Of course it didn't work, but I'm glad you were able to get the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

For woocommerce_price_format to work you need to set the format like this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_price_format', 'woo_custom_format_position', 999, 2);
     
    function woo_custom_format_position($format, $currency_pos)
    {
      /*'left':$format = '%1$s%2$s';
       'right':$format = '%2$s%1$s';
       'left_space':$format = '%1$s&nbsp;%2$s';
       'right_space':$format = '%2$s&nbsp;%1$s';
      */
        $format = '%1$s%2$s';//Change your position
        return $format;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason the 'position' setting wasn't working for EUR currency. I had to add this to my functions.php in order to fix it:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_price_format', 'woo_custom_format_position', 999, 2);
function woo_custom_format_position($format, $currency_pos)
{
  /*'left':$format = '%1$s%2$s';
   'right':$format = '%2$s%1$s';
   'left_space':$format = '%1$s&nbsp;%2$s';
   'right_space':$format = '%2$s&nbsp;%1$s';
  */
    switch ($currency_pos) {
        case 'left':
            return '%1$s%2$s';
        case 'right':
            return '%2$s%1$s';
        case 'left_space':
            return '%1$s&nbsp;%2$s';
        case 'right_space':
            return '%2$s&nbsp;%1$s';
        };
}
```

Now it actually uses the position chosen in the settings.

Hope it helps somebody!